# Installing using NUGet and Adding it to Project References

Tags: c#, nuget

I opened my project and it is using `EPPlus`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/
but its `reference` in the `References` was missing. So I installed it again using package manager console. But still it didn't add the reference to the References of the project.
I am not very familiar with `Nuget`, so when I install it in a project, it should automatically add the DLL to the References of the project or no?

Comment: What references are you missing? When I added it to my project it only added EPPlus to references.

Comment: @JohnOdom EPPlus is missing. When I install it with Nuget, it does "not" add it to my references.

Comment: That's strange. It should automatically add the DLL to the references. Have you tried creating a sample project and add EPPlus to it? I just did it with creating a sample console application and it was automatically added.

Comment: never mind...after uninstalling, this time I restarted the Visual Studio, Opened it in Admin mode, installed again. This time got added to References.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :).

Comment: You should add that as an answer, to help future visitors...

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled it.
Closed Visual Studio.
Opened with "Run As Admin"
Installed again.
worked this time.